# Google Maps Place Marker becomes un-clickable after certain zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Have a large number of place markers that are loaded in through a couple of KML files.  The KML is created from a PHP script but the rest of the controls are all done through JavaScript.  Up until a certain zoom level (appears to always correspond to half-way on the zoom control) there is an InfoWindow that loads whenever they are clicked.  However, after that half-way zoom level the markers become unresponsive.  Have been unsuccessful at figuring out any reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Does it work with only a few markers? Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: Been playing with it a bit.  The app loads 3 different KML marker layers.  When I switch one of them off, the markers remain clickable all the way down.  However, switching on the third breaks it again.  Even leaving the layer with only 17 markers in it off makes it work and then switching it back on = broken.
It shows the same behaviour in all the browsers we have tested; Chrome(mac and linux), Firefox(mac and linux), Safari (on mac and iPad).